# AngularJS, Stored items clear after adding new item

Tags: angularjs

We are able to add new items to the product array and store these values with NGStorage, We can switch routes and the new items are still stored like expected but if we go back and add another new item it clears all previous items added. If anyone can see what we're doing wrong please point it out. Thank you.

```
    $scope.Products = [];
    $scope.logItem = function($index,brandName,partNumber,productName,amount){
      alert("Item Logged");
      $scope.newItem = {
        Brand: brandName, 
        Part: partNumber, 
        Product: productName, 
        Amount: amount
      };
      $scope.Products.push($scope.newItem);
      $scope.$storage.Products = $scope.Products;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the controller gets initilized, you need to re-assign the $storage products to $scope.products

```
//$scope.Products = [];
     $scope.Products =  $scope.$storage.Products == undefined ? [] : $scope.$storage.Products; // Not exactly: like that when the controller gets initilized, you need to re-assign the $storage products to $scope.products
    $scope.logItem = function($index,brandName,partNumber,productName,amount){
      alert("Item Logged");
      $scope.newItem = {
        Brand: brandName, 
        Part: partNumber, 
        Product: productName, 
        Amount: amount
      };
      $scope.Products.push($scope.newItem);
      $scope.$storage.Products = $scope.Products;
    }
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you so much for all your help Dinesh :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you pass a reference to your Products array to your storage which in turn saves. But here you clear your array and thus your referenced storage:

$scope.Products = [];

Comment: If I remove $scope.Products = []; then none of this working, Any suggestions ?

Comment: What exactly is not working then? Do you get JS errors? Have you initialized $scope.Products once i.e. in your controller? I would move this $scope.Products = []; to an init method.

Comment: Currently when I add new items the JSON looks like this 

{
  "Products": [
    {
      "Brand": "Black and Decker",
      "Part": "ALM G123",
      "Product": "ALM GP006 Trim Cut® trimmer head and lines",
      "Amount": "10"
    },
    {
      "Brand": "Black and Decker",
      "Part": "ALM M356",
      "Product": "ALM MC114 Spool and line",
      "Amount": "20"
    }
  ]
}

If I remove $scope.Products = []; Then nothing goes into my JSON